# Time service -- interpreting the bytes

Tags: inetd

I tried installing `xinetd` and allowing some services such as `echo`, `time`, `daytime` by uncommenting them in `/etc/inetd.conf`

I tested it with nc:

```
$ nc localhost echo     #works like cat—✓
$ nc localhost daytime  #works like date—✓
```

But then I tried:

```
$ nc localhost time
# => weird characters
```

OK, time gives a binary timestamp, obviously.

So I thought I'd decipher it by converting it to a number and feeding that to `date -d @$number`:

```
$ nc localhost time |wc -c #=>4 (4 bytes)
$ alias reverseBytes="perl -0777e 'print scalar reverse <>'"
$ date -d $(nc localhost time | reverseBytes | od -An -tu4|sed 's/^ */@/')
```

Cool, now I'm getting accurate human-readable times, except the day is 70 years in the future.

What's wrong? (`openbds-inetd` gives the same results).

Comment: Tip: if you have GNU `od`, try `od --endian=big` instead of `reverseBytes`. Your `reverseBytes` will do the wrong thing when running on a big endian architecture because it would incorrectly reverse bytes that are already in the correct endian format.

Comment: Neat. I was originally going to say "bonus points for offering a better alternative to that perl hack."  Unfortunately, my system's `od` doesn't have that option (gnu coreutils 8.21).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time protocol ([RFC 868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc868)) is pretty unusual, not to mention archaic.

The time is encoded in binary, but on top of that, the epoch is 1900-01-01 00:00:00, not the standard UNIX epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00).

Decode it like this:

```
python -c 'import struct, sys; print(struct.unpack(">L", sys.stdin.read())[0]-2208988800)'
```

For example:

```
nc localhost time | python -c 'import struct, sys; print(struct.unpack(">L", sys.stdin.read())[0]-2208988800)'
```

Or just a little more work to turn it into a Python `datetime` object:

```
python -c 'import struct, sys, datetime; print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(struct.unpack(">L", sys.stdin.read())[0]-2208988800)))'
```